# Machine learning classify function with audio and set of pictures

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, sound

As I see from documentation, Classify function supports Audio and Pictures as input, video is not supported unfortunately :(

Will it work if I try to use classify for mixed data input like

```
Classify[{Audio1, {Picture1.1, Picture1.2, Picture1.3}}->"Train arrival", {Audio2, {Picture2.1, Picture2.2, Picture2.3, Picture2.4}}->"Plane arrival"]
```

especially when pictures array is not the same size.
here {Audio1, {Picture1.1, Picture1.2, Picture1.3}} is an extraction from video.

Or my expectation from classify is too high?

**UPDATE1:**

When I run my example to classify this data {Audio1, {Picture1.1, Picture1.2, Picture1.3}} I got something like this. looks like mathematica does not recognize it as audio.

[image]

I load sample data like this

```
{Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> 
   "SampleData/Audio_Pics_separated/01/*.wav"], 
 Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> 
   "SampleData/Audio_Pics_separated/01/*.jpg"]}
```

**UPDATE2**

When I run example from Alexey's answer I got many errors like this

[image]

The same happens if I load audio from wav file by import command.

Is it OK and I can ignore these errors or these errors means that my classifier function will not work at all?

UPDATE3: There are 2 option how to fix errors mentioned in UPDATE2.

1. Sign in with Wolfram ID inside Mathematica
2. Disconnect Mathematica from internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work.

```
audio = {AudioGenerator["White", 3], AudioGenerator["Pink", 4]};
images = Table[RandomImage[1, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], {7}];

X = Riffle[audio, TakeList[images, {3, 4}]] // Partition[#, 2] &;
Y = {1, 2};

c = Classify[X -> Y, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]
```

[image]

```
ClassifierInformation[c]
```

[image]

```
Options[c][[1]]["Model"]["Network"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. when I run my example, it looks different from yours. I put screenshot to the question. looks like mathematica does not recognize it as audio, but get it as NominalVector. Also in your example, second input is nominalsequence, but I was expecting an image.

P.S. Я тоже Алексей :)

Comment: @Zlelik Nice to meet you :) 1. Try: `Audio /@ Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "SampleData/Audio_Pics_separated/01/*.wav"]`. Additionally you can set feature types `Classify[...,FeatureTypes->{"Audio",...}]`. 2. I think it's okay that second feature has type NominalSequence because you have variable number of images for each example.

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try.

Comment: It is strange. If I try like this `zzz = {
  {Audio /@ Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "SampleData/Audio_Pics_separated/1/*.wav"], 
    Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "SampleData/Audio_Pics_separated/1/*.jpg"]} -> 1,
  {Audio /@ Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "SampleData/Audio_Pics_separated/2/*.wav"], 
    Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "SampleData/Audio_Pics_separated/2/*.jpg"]} -> 2
  }
ccc = Classify[zzz]`

it works without errors but still tells me nominalvector, instead of audio. If I add `FeatureTypes -> {"Audio", Automatic}` It gives me error

Comment: Error text: `Classify::mlincfttp: Incompatible variable type (Audio) and variable value ({Audio[RawArray[Integer16,<2,96096>],SignedInteger16,Appearance->Automatic,AudioOutputDevice->Automatic,SampleRate->48000,SoundVolume->1]}).`

Comment: I am getting strange errors when I try to classify just audio. When I run your example I got the same errors. I put screenshot in UPDATE2.

Comment: @Zlelik Sorry for the late response. Was busy last weeks. Try to reinstall your Mathematica. No errors in the Cloud: https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/22bed57c-fd20-4a3b-889c-4f33352da414

Comment: Looks like these errors happen only if mathematica is not logined to Wolfram Cloud. I found 2 ways to fix it: 1st is to login to Wolfram Cloud with Wolfram ID and second option is to disconnect mathematica from the internet.